# Connecting to Azure SQL via R

Tags: sql, r, azure

The code below lets me connect to Azure SQL server via R.  However, I can only access a 'master' database and not the two databases below which I created.  Tables show as blank, any ideas?  Thanks

```
        library(RODBC) library(dplyr) library(DBI) 

    conn <- RODBC::odbcConnect(
        > dsn = "XXX",   uid = "XXX",   pwd = "XXX" )
        > 
        > db_list <- RODBC::sqlQuery(   channel = conn,   query = "SELECT name
        > FROM Master..sysdatabases")
        > 
        > test <- sqlTables(conn)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend that you use the "odbc" package, which to my experience is the most robust and versatile R package for connection to databases. When making a connection with this package you write explicitly which database you connect to.

```
# Library
library(odbc)

# Creating connection
my_connection <- dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(),
                           Driver = "SQL Driver",
                           server = "azuredatabase.azure.com,port",
                           database = "databasename",
                           uid = "user",
                           pwd = "password")
```

Comment: No problem - I have been through the whole database connection mess some years back, and since I got into "odbc" there has been no looking back :D

Answer (score 0):

Esben's answer worked perfectly for me (thanks Esben!). Added a minor change in the driver portion from
Driver = "SQL Driver" to
Driver = "SQL Server"

and am now seeing the database appear in the connections pane.