# How can I connect to an Azure SQL Server Database from R?

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, odbc

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL Server Database from R, so I can create a table and upload data to the database.

[This is how I connect to the server in SQL Server Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR2Tx.png)

I have tried the following:

```
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "server_name, 1433",
                 Database = "database_name",
                 uid = "me@domain.com",
                 pwd = "password")
```

This results in the error:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: HY000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open server "domain.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.

```
library(RODBC)

con.text <- paste("DRIVER={"SQL Server"}",
                  ";Database=database_name",
                  ";Server=server_name",
                  ",1433",
                  ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP",
                  ";trusted_connection=true",
                  sep="")

con <- odbcDriverConnect(con.text)
```

This results in the warning messages:

> 1: In odbcDriverConnect(con.text) :
> [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 40607, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.

> 2: In odbcDriverConnect(con.text) :
> [RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute

> 3: In odbcDriverConnect(con.text) : ODBC connection failed

How can I successfully connect to this server from R?

Comment: Does [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601944/390122) help you when using `library(odbc)`? Note that they're using a DSN rather than a server name in the `dbConnect` parameters.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for the suggestion, but that results in this error:

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: IM010: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long

Answer (score 1):

> **Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: HY000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server**
> **Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open server "domain.com" requested by the**
> **login. The login failed.**

The above error is mainly caused because of driver problem. Use this command to check whether drivers are properly installed or not.

```
 library(odbc) 
 sort(unique(odbcListDrivers()[[1]]))
```

Connect ***Azure SQL database*** from ***R*** ,follow this **Syntax:**

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(RODBC)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                            Driver = "[your driver's name]", 
                            Server = "[your server's path]", 
                            Database = "[your database's name]", 
                            UID = "Database user", 
                            PWD = "Database password",
                            Port = 1433)
```

Please follow the below reference it has detailed information about connecting Azure SQL to R in a detailed way:

[Connecting to Azure SQL via R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836310/connecting-to-azure-sql-via-r)

https://db.rstudio.com/getting-started/connect-to-database

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkcBwYjHYOc